# How to convert an int value to string in Go?

Tags: string, go, int, converters

```
i := 123
s := string(i)
```

s is 'E', but what I want is "123"

Please tell me how can I get "123".

And in Java, I can do in this way:

```
String s = "ab" + "c"  // s is "abc"
```

how can I `concat` two strings in Go?

Comment: The second question (string concatenation) has [an answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1760757/477035) that covers efficiency.

Comment: `strconv.Itoa(i)` (int to ASCII) to set an int to a string. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737936/12817546. `strconv.Atoi(s)` (ASCII to int) to set a string to an int. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740786/12817546.

Answer (score 1209, accepted):

Use the [`strconv`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa) package's `Itoa` function.

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "strconv"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    t := strconv.Itoa(123)
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

You can concat strings simply by `+`'ing them, or by using the `Join` function of the [`strings`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join) package.

Comment: If you have a lot of string concatenations to do (for example to build a long string) and want your code to be faster and with less allocations, you should consider using bytes.Buffer too (it's a kind of more generic version of Java's StringBuilder).

Comment: Why did the language designers think that cryptic functions names like "Itoa" were preferable to something that might be a little more descriptive?

Comment: @luke it comes from the C heritage where the entire machine might have 256K memory; usability was sacrificed to fit more functionality in.  The creators of Go are all deeply embedded in that heritage and feel entirely comfortable with these names.

Comment: Putting history above accessibility and ease of learning is bad design IMO. :(

Comment: @Luke Depends on who your target users are and how strong the convention is. Some UIs still have a floppy disk as the Save icon :)

Comment: @Luke I hate that you're being so logical and right about this. These hints of C-like crypticness are part of Go's sex appeal! 

Comment: for easy remembering name **ItoA** - **Integer to ASCII**

Comment: `bytes.Buffer` will bite your fingers if you continue using it. Use `strings.Builder` instead.

Comment: @IvanAracki easy to remember because that's what it stands for

Comment: @Bryan Except then they make tons of random changes to make it not like C, such as putting the type after the name when you declare a variable.

Comment: @sudo read [this blog post](https://blog.golang.org/gos-declaration-syntax) to see why the type after the name is a better design

Comment: @IvanAracki very helpful. I quoted you in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737936/12817546. I guess Atoi is "ASCII to integer".

Comment: `Itoa` does only `return FormatInt(int64(i), 10)`. IMO the `FormatInt` function is neither cryptic nor bad design. And I really like how the shortcut here, i.e. `Itoa` is a nod to the same method in C.

Comment: I love how this comment section has decided it's the place to determine the value of Go's roots and design decisions.

Comment: Iota probably stands for (I)nteger (to) (a)scii. So it is not cryptic as we might think.

Comment: @luke It's not strictly part of the language. It's a library and you can change that if you really want to. I like 'from' more than 'to' because reading left to right I see the LHS being the type I get and the L value and the RHS being what I provide in the function e.g. aString := StringFromInteger(1234)

Answer (score 205):

```
fmt.Sprintf("%v",value);
```

If you know the specific type of value use the corresponding formatter for example `%d` for `int`

More info - [fmt](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)

Comment: I would not recommend this, as this is far less efficient than other conversion methods because it uses reflection.

Comment: But if you don't know the specific type, Sprintf is the way to go.

Comment: I heard the implementation of sprintf in c to parse a json file was the reason GTA's online  mode used to take around 14 minutes to start.
An Indie dev pointed it out and the load time got all the way down to ~1.5 minutes

Answer (score 96):

`fmt.Sprintf`, `strconv.Itoa` and `strconv.FormatInt` will do the job. But `Sprintf` will use the package `reflect`, and it will allocate one more object,  so it's not an efficient choice.

[image]

Comment: And `strconv.FormatUint()` for `uint64` -> `string`

Answer (score 84):

It is interesting to note that `strconv.Itoa` is [shorthand](https://golang.org/src/strconv/itoa.go?s=783:806#L14) for

```
func FormatInt(i int64, base int) string
```

with base 10

For Example:

```
strconv.Itoa(123)
```

is equivalent to

```
strconv.FormatInt(int64(123), 10)
```

Comment: Interesting to note that calling FormatInt() directly instead of Itoa() saves 0.1 nanosecond according to the benchmark at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38077508/968244

Answer (score 46):

You can use [fmt.Sprintf](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) or [strconv.FormatFloat](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatFloat)

For example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    val := 14.7
    s := fmt.Sprintf("%f", val)
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

Answer (score 34):

In this case both `strconv` and `fmt.Sprintf` do the same job but using the `strconv` package's `Itoa` function is the best choice, because `fmt.Sprintf` allocate one more object during conversion.

[image: check the nenchmark result of both]
check the benchmark here: https://gist.github.com/evalphobia/caee1602969a640a4530

see https://play.golang.org/p/hlaz_rMa0D for example.

Comment: @Boon In visible impact to your app? As always - it depends.

Another object means one more object, beyond the obvious temporary small memory hit, needs to be garbage collected. If you are calling the function at high rates, for example as part of some serialization process used whenever a message is received from somewhere, it could have a significant impact.

Since `fmt.Sprintf` and `strconv.iota` are similar in terms of ease of use and the above data shows iota to be faster with lower GC impact, it appears that `iota` should be used in general when a single integer needs converting.

Comment: Seems like premature optimization to me to be thinking at this level so soon. Best is to write readable code first.

Comment: @Boon They're equally readable. Might as well use the faster one. Also, what's to say a new Golang programmer isn't starting with something that does lots of these conversions? I'm an experienced programmer writing my first Golang code right now and am in that situation.

Answer (score 16):

Another option:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   n := 123
   s := fmt.Sprint(n)
   fmt.Println(s == "123")
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Sprint

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the a convenient and easy to remember solution (my point of view).

Answer (score 14):

Converting `int64`:

```
n := int64(32)
str := strconv.FormatInt(n, 10)

fmt.Println(str)
// Prints "32"
```

Answer (score 8):

ok,most of them have shown you something good.
Let'me give you this:

```golang
// ToString Change arg to string
func ToString(arg interface{}, timeFormat ...string) string {
    if len(timeFormat) > 1 {
        log.SetFlags(log.Llongfile | log.LstdFlags)
        log.Println(errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("timeFormat's length should be one")))
    }
    var tmp = reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(arg)).Interface()
    switch v := tmp.(type) {
    case int:
        return strconv.Itoa(v)
    case int8:
        return strconv.FormatInt(int64(v), 10)
    case int16:
        return strconv.FormatInt(int64(v), 10)
    case int32:
        return strconv.FormatInt(int64(v), 10)
    case int64:
        return strconv.FormatInt(v, 10)
    case string:
        return v
    case float32:
        return strconv.FormatFloat(float64(v), 'f', -1, 32)
    case float64:
        return strconv.FormatFloat(v, 'f', -1, 64)
    case time.Time:
        if len(timeFormat) == 1 {
            return v.Format(timeFormat[0])
        }
        return v.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
    case jsoncrack.Time:
        if len(timeFormat) == 1 {
            return v.Time().Format(timeFormat[0])
        }
        return v.Time().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05")
    case fmt.Stringer:
        return v.String()
    case reflect.Value:
        return ToString(v.Interface(), timeFormat...)
    default:
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! You may include uint+uint8-64 to have a complete list

Comment: Or you could just use `fmt.Sprint` that does the same (except for `time.Time` and `jsoncrack.Time` (a package that will add dependencies I have never heard of) values).

Answer (score 4):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt" 
    "strconv"
)

func main(){
//First question: how to get int string?

    intValue := 123
    // keeping it in separate variable : 
    strValue := strconv.Itoa(intValue) 
    fmt.Println(strValue)

//Second question: how to concat two strings?

    firstStr := "ab"
    secondStr := "c"
    s := firstStr + secondStr
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```