# Does Go support operator type variables?

Tags: variables, go, operators, variable-assignment

This is might not be such a good question, since I don't know of any compiled language that supports this feature, but since Go is constantly surprising me, I'll ask it anyway:

For my own practice, I am writing a little calculator program in Go. I'm wondering if there is a way I can declare and assign a variable of type "Operator", such that I could, for example, write:

```
var o Operator

o = +

var o1 Operator

o1 = /
```

and write function like this

```
func DoOperation(a,b int,o Operator) int{

    return a o b

}
```

(No, I am not asking about operator overloading.)

Offhand, I don't know of any compiled language that supports such a thing (I'm not an expert in this).  I did look at the docs under operators and found nothing. Can Go surprise me again?

**Edit:**  The accepted answer states that Haskell supports this,

Comment: Any particular reason this was downvoted? Since Haskell supports this, as per @tomwilde's answer, it is not a dumb question and I did look at the docs under operators and found nothing, but Go seems to have its share of 'easter eggs'

Comment: Io can do stuff like this.

Comment: @dethtron5000 - interesting. Never heard of `Io` before, just looked it up - not a mainstream language I guess... :) I see it runs in a virtual machine. Does it compile to something akin to Java bytecode or MSIL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, Go operators are not functions and hence no valid right-hand expressions. They work in a generic way e.g. the plus-operator works on all numeric types and infix-notation a la haskell is not supported either.

You would have to write your own "soft"-generic addition function using reflection.

One compiled language that covers all of your requirements is Haskell.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do exactly what you say, but you can use functions instead. You have to write functions for each operator, but that's relatively little code.

```
type BinaryOperator func(a, b int) int

func OpAdd(a, b int) int { return a + b }
func OpSub(a, b int) int { return a - b }

func ApplyBinaryOperator(a, b int, op BinaryOperator) int {
    return op(a, b)
}
```

Comment: Sorry I can't accept both answers. But @tomwilde was first, and more technically detailed. But your workaround is an **excellent** idea that I will probably implement.

Comment: Note that this example still works if you drop the BinaryOperator( ) around the func literals: var OpAdd = func(a, b int) int { return a + b } and similarly for OpSub.

Comment: Thanks Russ! I changed the code to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: If you don't want to manually make all of the operators yourself, I have a package here that does it with generics: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tawesoft/golib/v2/operator e.g. here `ApplyBinaryOperator(a, b, operator.Add[int])`

Answer (score 0):

Coming from an oop background I started doing this :

```
package main

import "fmt"
type MyInt int64

func (i * MyInt) Add(n MyInt) * MyInt {
    *i += n
    return i
}

func (i MyInt) String() string {
    v := int64(i)
    return fmt.Sprintf("0x%x (%d)", v, v)
}

func main() {
    x := MyInt(10)
    x.Add(10).Add(20).Add(30)
    fmt.Println("x = ", x)
}
```

Comment: I prefer the approach in @Anonymous's answer - it's nothing but good old fashioned function pointers, just doing it Go style (making it clear and simple) and keeping it generic, although your approach could also work with a similar design pattern. Also see [How to convert a int value to string in go?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105935/how-to-convert-a-int-value-to-string-in-go)