# How to convert uint32 to string?

Tags: go

I need to convert an `uint32` to `string`. How can I do that? `strconv.Itoa` doesn't seem to work.

Long story:
 
I need to convert an UID received through the imap package to `string` so that I can set it later as a sequence. As a side note I'm wondering why such conversions are difficult in Go. A cast `string(t)` could have been so much easier.

Comment: itoa doesn't work with uint32 // code UIDI := imap.AsNumber(rsp.MessageInfo().UID)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I would simply use Sprintf or even just Sprint:

```
var n uint32 = 42
str := fmt.Sprint(n)
println(str)
```

Go is strongly typed. Casting a number directly to a string would not make sense. Think about C where string are `char *` which is a pointer to the first letter of the string terminated by `\0`. Casting a number to a string would result in having the first letter pointer to the address of the number, which does not make sense. This is why you need to "actively" convert.

Answer (score 89):

I would do this using [`strconv.FormatUint`](http://golang.org/pkg/strconv#FormatUint):

```
import "strconv"

var u uint32 = 17
var s = strconv.FormatUint(uint64(u), 10)
// "17"
```

Note that the expected parameter is `uint64`, so you have to cast your `uint32` first. There is no specific `FormatUint32` function.

Comment: This solution turns out to be the faster. Therefore I would recommend it to be used.

`BenchmarkUintStrconv-8    50000000         36.8 ns/op`
vs.
`BenchmarkUintSprint-8     20000000        118 ns/op`

Answer (score 7):

To summarize:

> strconv.Itoa doesn't seem to work

[`strconv.Itoa`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa) accepts `int`, which is signed integer (either 32 or 64 bit), architecture-dependent type (see [Numeric types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)).

> I need to convert an uint32 to string

1. Use [`fmt.Sprint`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprint)
2. Use [`strconv.FormatUint`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatUint)

The **better option** is `strconv.FormatUint` because it is faster, has less memory allocations (benchmark examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37542656/9811969) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39444005/9811969)).

> A cast string(t) could have been so much easier.

Using `string` does not work as some people expect, see [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type):

> Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer. Values outside the range of valid Unicode code points are converted to "\uFFFD".

This function is going to be removed from Go2, see Rob Pike's [proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3939)

Answer (score 1):

For a more robust solution, you can use `text/template`:

```
package main

import (
   "text/template"
   "strings"
)

func format(s string, v interface{}) string {
   t, b := new(template.Template), new(strings.Builder)
   template.Must(t.Parse(s)).Execute(b, v)
   return b.String()
}

func main() {
   imap := struct{UID uint32}{999}
   s := format("{{.UID}}", imap)
   println(s == "999")
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/text/template