# How to write integers in a file using Golang?

Tags: go

1. I generate numbers from 0 to 10
2. I create a file
3. And I try to write to the file by converting integers to string

But when I open the h.txt file there is nothing written

How to fix this and have the numbers written to the h.txt file?

```
package main

import "os"

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ { // Generating...

        f, _ := os.Create("h.txt") // creating...

        f.WriteString(string(i)) // writing...

        defer f.Close()
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're not checking the error on `os.Create`, make sure that's nil before writing the file.

Comment: You need to use `strconv` or `fmt.Sprintf` to convert `integer` to `string`. Take a look at [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105935/how-to-convert-an-int-value-to-string-in-go).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

1) You're opening the file multiple times, every iteration of your loop; `os.Create` will truncate the file if it already exists, so you may be writing and truncating it on each iteration.

2) You're not checking that the file opens correctly without error

3) `defer` schedules code to run when the function ends, not at the end of the scope. (i.e. at the end of the iteration)

4) You should convert the integer properly, using a conversion and checking the error: `_, err := f.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%d",i))`, and then check the error.

Try this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Create("h.txt") // creating...
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error creating file: %v", err)
        return
    }
    defer f.Close()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ { // Generating...
        _, err = f.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%d\n", i)) // writing...
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("error writing string: %v", err)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks John for reply, +1

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to upvote and accept if this solves your issue @MarcusPereira

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `fmt.Fprintf(f, "%d\n", i)` instead of `f.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%d\n", i))`?

Answer (score -1):

Try like this for write generated numbers to file:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    // If the file doesn't exist, create it, or append to the file
    f, err := os.OpenFile("h.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for i:=0;i<10;i++ { // Generate and write...
        if _, err := f.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%d ",i))); err != nil {
            defer f.Close() 
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}
```

How you can see, for write to file we need `int` convert to `[]byte` like this:

```
[]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%d ",i))
```