# Int to string in go?

Tags: go

I really thought this would be as simple as :

```
string(myInt)
```

It appears not.

I am writing a function which takes a slice of ints, and appends each one to a string - and adds a separator between each one. Here is my code.

```
func(xis *Int16Slice) ConvertToStringWithSeparator(separator string) string{
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    for i, value := range *xis{
        buffer.WriteString(string(value))
        if i != len(*xis) -1 {
            buffer.WriteString(separator)
        }
    }
    return buffer.String()
}
```

Please read the sentence below. This is not a duplicate of [How to convert an int value to string in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105935) - because : 
I am aware of things like the strconv.Itoa function, but it appears as though that will only work on "regular" ints. It will not support an int16

Comment: Not a duplicate. The final sentence in my question points out that the Itoa function (the solution to that question, which uses standard int types), does not support my data here.

Comment: So do an inline conversion: `strconv.Itoa(int(value))`

Comment: the question of how to convert an string to an int is absolutelly valid! i guess that the ConvertToStringWithSeparator is not the main topic of the question, is something related to another task that make wide the answer. For example, in my personal opinion i would strike your problem thinking in more little things that can be combined for achieve the ConvertToStringWithSeparator-goal, so first the conversion of scalar value, then apply the conversion to each element of the slice,and then apply a join that concatenates all of the elements in a slice into a string separated by a given char.

Comment: `strconv.Itoa(int(i))` (int to ASCII) or fmt.Sprintf("%d", i)
to set an int to a string. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737936/12817546 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740786/12817546.  `strconv.Atoi(s)` (ASCII to int) to set a string to an int. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62740786/12817546.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`strconv.Itoa`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Itoa) (or [`strconv.FormatInt`](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#FormatInt) if performance is critical) by simply converting the `int16` to an `int` or `int64`, for example ([Go Playground](https://play.golang.com/p/5KcuYxsB9F3)):

```
x := uint16(123)
strconv.Itoa(int(x))            // => "123"
strconv.FormatInt(int64(x), 10) // => "123"
```

Note that `strconv.FormatInt(...)` may be slightly faster according to a simple benchmark:

```
// itoa_test.go
package main

import (
  "strconv"
  "testing"
)

const x = int16(123)

func Benchmark_Itoa(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    strconv.Itoa(int(x))
  }
}

func Benchmark_FormatInt(b *testing.B) {
  for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    strconv.FormatInt(int64(x), 10)
  }
}
```

Run as `$ go test -bench=. ./itoa_test.go`:

```
goos: darwin
goarch: amd64
Benchmark_Itoa-8            50000000            30.3 ns/op
Benchmark_FormatInt-8       50000000            27.8 ns/op
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  2.976s
```

Comment: I love this answer. We need more people like you.

Answer (score 5):

you can use Sprintf:

```
  num := 33
  str := fmt.Sprintf("%d", num)
  fmt.Println(str)
```

or Itoa

```
str := strconv.Itoa(3)
```

Comment: Sprintf is expensive, as it creates items, I'd like to do this inline line if possible :P

Comment: just edited my answer, added another way using strconv.Itoa

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the int16 to int and then use the strconv.Itoa function to convert int16 to string.

Ex: https://play.golang.org/p/pToOjqDKEoi