# How to print linked list

Tags: go, linked-list

Below is the code:

```
package collection

type List struct {
    head *Node
    tail *Node
}

func (l *List) First() *Node {
    return l.head
}

func (l *List) Push(value int) {
    node := &Node{value: value}
    if l.head == nil { // list is empty
        l.head = node
    } else {
        l.tail.next = node
    }
    l.tail = node
}

func (l *List) String() string {
    var list string
    n := l.First()
    for n != nil {
        list = list + string(n.Value()) + " "
        n = n.Next()
    }
    return list
}

type Node struct {
    value int
    next  *Node
}

func (n *Node) Next() *Node {
    return n.next
}

func (n *Node) Value() int {
    return n.value
}
```

---

On debugging, elements get pushed successfully

But for `list = list + string(n.Value()) + " "`, this is the debug output: `list: " "`

---

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/myhub/cs61a/collection"
)

func main() {
    l := &collection.List{}
    l.Push(1)
    l.Push(2)
    l.Push(3)
    fmt.Println(l)
}
```

---

1) Why `list = list + string(n.Value()) + " "` does not concat integers?

2) How to support `Node` for member `value` of any type?

Comment: 1) In order to convert an int to a string, you need to use [`strconv.Itoa`](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv?tab=doc#Itoa). There's a [question covering that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105935/how-to-convert-an-int-value-to-string-in-go). 2) That's harder in Go as it doesn't have generics, so you would need to use an `interface{}` (empty interface) to make it work. You would also have make many type assertions. A better way would be using normal slices as they can support many types with type safety

Comment: Try `strconv.Itoa(n.Value())` instead

Comment: @xarantolus Why `string(n.Value())` is not giving compile time error, when it cannot do type conversion?

Comment: It does do a type conversion, they're just character values 1, 2, and 3 which are non-printable characters.

Comment: @Marc Got you... character with ascii value(or UTF-8 value may be) 1 is non-printable character, yes

Comment: @Marc `strconv.Itoa()` does something different from type conversion?

Comment: Yes, as spelled out in [the docs](https://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#example_Itoa), it returns the string representation of the integer in base 10.

Comment: You can check the [code](https://golang.org/src/strconv/itoa.go) also to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Use `strconv.Itoa()` to convert int into string.

```
list = list + strconv.Itoa(n.Value()) + " "
```

In a plain conversion, the value is interpreted as a Unicode code point, and the resulting string will contain the character represented by that code point, encoded in UTF-8.

```
s := string(97) // s == "a"
```

and for your case 1,2,3 are all non-printable characters