# Iterating over go string and making string from chars in go

Tags: string, go

I started learning go and I want to implement some algorithm. I can iterate over strings and then get chars, but these chars are Unicode numbers.

How to concatenate chars into strings in go? Do you have some reference? I was unable to find anything about primitives in official page.

Comment: well what the hell is a "char"? There is no such type in Go

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Iterating over strings using [`range`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) gives you Unicode characters while
iterating over a string using an index gives you bytes. See the spec for
[runes](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals) and [strings](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) as well as their [conversions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type).

As The New Idiot mentioned, strings can be concatenated using the [`+`
operator](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators).

The conversion from character to string is two-fold. You can convert
a `byte` (or byte sequence) to a string:

```
string(byte('A'))
```

or you can convert a `rune` (or rune sequence) to a string:

```
string(rune('µ'))
```

The difference is that runes represent Unicode characters while bytes represent
8 bit values.

But all of this is mentioned in the respective sections of the spec I linked above. 
It's quite easy to understand, you should definitely read it.

Comment: Thank you for explaining difference between iterating with index and `range`

Answer (score 3):

you can convert a `[]rune` to a string directly:

```
string([]rune{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '☃'})
```

http://play.golang.org/p/P9vKXlo47c

as for reference, it's in the Conversions section of the Go spec, in the section titled "Conversions to and from a string type"

http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions

as for concatenation, you probably don't want to concatenate every single character with the `+` operator, since that will perform a lot of copying under the hood.  If you're getting runes in one at a time and you're not building an intermediate slice of runes, you most likely want to use a `bytes.Buffer`, which has a `WriteRune` method for this sort of thing.  http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.WriteRune

Answer (score 2):

Use `+`

```
str:= str + "a"
```

You can try something like this :

```
string1 := "abc"
character1 := byte('A')
string1 += string(character1)
```

Even [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1766304/1163607) might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

definetly worth reading @nemo's post

Iterating over strings using range gives you Unicode characters while iterating over a string using an index gives you bytes. See the spec for runes and strings as well as their conversions.

Strings can be concatenated using the + operator.

The conversion from character to string is two-fold. You can convert a byte (or byte sequence) to a string:

```
string(byte('A'))
```

or you can convert a rune (or rune sequence) to a string:

```
string(rune('µ'))
```