# Golang string format using slice values

Tags: string, go, format, slice

Here I am trying to create a query string for my API from a slice containing strings.

ie. `where={"node_name":"node1","node_name":"node_2"}`

```
import (
   "fmt"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
    nodes := []string{"node1", "node2"}
    var query string
    for _, n := range nodes {
        query += fmt.Sprintf("\"node_name\":\"%s\",", n)
    }
    query = strings.TrimRight(query, ",")
    final := fmt.Sprintf("where={%s}", query)
    fmt.Println(final)
}
```

Here is [goplayground](https://play.golang.org/p/uz52k2Soyi) link.

What is the best way to get the result?

Comment: this should get you started? https://play.golang.org/p/MazNqAD_Yd

Comment: thanks for the comment, but i want in that format `where={"node_name":"node1","node_name":"node_2"}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your solution uses way too many allocations due to `string` concatenations.

We'll create some alternative, faster and/or more elegant solutions. Note that the below solutions do not check if node values contain the quotation mark `"` character. If they would, those would have to be escaped somehow (else the result would be an invalid query string).

The complete, runnable code can be found on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QAVpmzhCgs). The complete testing / benchmarking code can also be found on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QDpgFSosUc), but it is not runnable, save both to your Go workspace (e.g. `$GOPATH/src/query/query.go` and `$GOPATH/src/query/query_test.go`) and run it with `go test -bench .`.

Also be sure to check out this related question: [How to efficiently concatenate strings in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760757/how-to-efficiently-concatenate-strings-in-go)

## Alternatives

#### Genesis

Your logic can be captured by the following function:

```
func buildOriginal(nodes []string) string {
    var query string
    for _, n := range nodes {
        query += fmt.Sprintf("\"node_name\":\"%s\",", n)
    }
    query = strings.TrimRight(query, ",")
    return fmt.Sprintf("where={%s}", query)
}
```

#### Using `bytes.Buffer`

Much better would be to use a single buffer, e.g. [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer), build the query in that, and convert it to `string` at the end:

```
func buildBuffer(nodes []string) string {
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    buf.WriteString("where={")
    for i, v := range nodes {
        if i > 0 {
            buf.WriteByte(',')
        }
        buf.WriteString(`"node_name":"`)
        buf.WriteString(v)
        buf.WriteByte('"')
    }
    buf.WriteByte('}')
    return buf.String()
}
```

Using it:

```
nodes := []string{"node1", "node2"}
fmt.Println(buildBuffer(nodes))
```

Output:

```
where={"node_name":"node1","node_name":"node2"}
```

#### `bytes.Buffer` improved

`bytes.Buffer` will still do some reallocations, although much less than your original solution.

However, we can still reduce the allocations to 1, if we pass a big-enough byte slice when creating the `bytes.Buffer` using [`bytes.NewBuffer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewBuffer). We can calculate the required size prior:

```
func buildBuffer2(nodes []string) string {
    size := 8 + len(nodes)*15
    for _, v := range nodes {
        size += len(v)
    }
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, size))
    buf.WriteString("where={")
    for i, v := range nodes {
        if i > 0 {
            buf.WriteByte(',')
        }
        buf.WriteString(`"node_name":"`)
        buf.WriteString(v)
        buf.WriteByte('"')
    }
    buf.WriteByte('}')
    return buf.String()
}
```

Note that in `size` calculation `8` is the size of the string `where={}` and `15` is the size of the string `"node_name":"",`.

#### Using `text/template`

We can also create a text template, and use the [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) package to execute it, efficiently generating the result:

```
var t = template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ))

func buildTemplate(nodes []string) string {
    size := 8 + len(nodes)*15
    for _, v := range nodes {
        size += len(v)
    }
    buf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, size))
    if err := t.Execute(buf, nodes); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) // Handle error
    }
    return buf.String()
}

const templ = `where={
{{- range $idx, $n := . -}}
    {{if ne $idx 0}},{{end}}"node_name":"{{$n}}"
{{- end -}}
}`
```

#### Using `strings.Join()`

This solution is interesting due to its simplicity. We can use [`strings.Join()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Join) to join the nodes with the static text `","node_name":"` in between, proper prefix and postfix applied.

An important thing to note: `strings.Join()` uses the builtin [`copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) function with a single preallocated `[]byte` buffer, so it's very fast! *"As a special case, it (the `copy()` function) also will copy bytes from a string to a slice of bytes."*

```
func buildJoin(nodes []string) string {
    if len(nodes) == 0 {
        return "where={}"
    }
    return `where={"node_name":"` + strings.Join(nodes, `","node_name":"`) + `"}`
}
```

## Benchmark results

We'll benchmark with the following `nodes` value:

```
var nodes = []string{"n1", "node2", "nodethree", "fourthNode",
    "n1", "node2", "nodethree", "fourthNode",
    "n1", "node2", "nodethree", "fourthNode",
    "n1", "node2", "nodethree", "fourthNode",
    "n1", "node2", "nodethree", "fourthNode",
}
```

And the benchmarking code looks like this:

```
func BenchmarkOriginal(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        buildOriginal(nodes)
    }
}

func BenchmarkBuffer(b *testing.B) {
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        buildBuffer(nodes)
    }
}

// ... All the other benchmarking functions look the same
```

And now the results:

```
BenchmarkOriginal-4               200000             10572 ns/op
BenchmarkBuffer-4                 500000              2914 ns/op
BenchmarkBuffer2-4               1000000              2024 ns/op
BenchmarkBufferTemplate-4          30000             77634 ns/op
BenchmarkJoin-4                  2000000               830 ns/op
```

Some unsurprising facts: `buildBuffer()` is **3.6 times** faster than `buildOriginal()`, and `buildBuffer2()` (with pre-calculated size) is about **30%** faster than `buildBuffer()` because it does not need to reallocate (and copy over) the internal buffer.

Some surprising facts: `buildJoin()` is extremely fast, even beats `buildBuffer2()` by **2.4 times** (due to only using a `[]byte` and `copy()`). `buildTemplate()` on the other hand proved quite slow: **7 times** slower than `buildOriginal()`. The main reason for this is because it uses (has to use) reflection under the hood.

Comment: Learn so many things from your answer, thank you so much. Hope many others golang folks also learn from this answer.