# Is there a more efficient way to concatenate strings?

Tags: go, pipe

I have written an example of Go code which is sends query to postgres and send result to the pager:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    connstr := "user=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=disable"
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connstr)
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT schemaname, relname, seq_scan FROM pg_stat_all_tables ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 10")
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
    defer rows.Close()

    var buf string
    for rows.Next() {
        var s, r string
        var ss int
        if err := rows.Scan(&s, &r, &ss); err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
        buf = fmt.Sprintf("%s %s %d\n", buf + s, r, ss)
    }
    
    cmd := exec.Command("less")
    cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(buf)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    
    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
}
```

But the following line:

```
buf = fmt.Sprintf("%s %s %d\n", buf + s, r, ss)
```

looks rude for me and I'm not sure this is a right way. Is there way to achieve result in more elegant way? May be it's possible with some kind of buffers and io.Readers?

UPD. When I asked this question a few year ago, I was a Golang newbie. Now, with current experience I see no problems with this code and the question should be closed.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code and in what way do you want to improve it?

Comment: If `fmt.Sprintf` results in the desired output, there is no problem!

Comment: I think used way is not performance-wise and Golang must have something better than that ))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strings in Go are immutable and every time when you assign a new value to a variable it must create a new string and copy contents of existing one to it.

You can use `bytes.Buffer` instead of `string` to avoid recreation on each iteration.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
    "os"
    "bytes"
)

func main() {
    connstr := "user=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=disable"
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connstr)
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT schemaname, relname, seq_scan FROM pg_stat_all_tables ORDER BY 1 LIMIT 10")
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
    defer rows.Close()

    var buf = new(bytes.Buffer)
    for rows.Next() {
        var s, r string
        var ss int
        if err := rows.Scan(&s, &r, &ss); err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
        buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%s %s %d\n", s, r, ss))
    }

    cmd := exec.Command("less")
    cmd.Stdin = buf
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout

    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil { log.Fatal(err) }
}
```

Btw, the string builder was added in Go 1.10 https://godoc.org/strings#Builder

Read more about string concatenation benchmarks: http://herman.asia/efficient-string-concatenation-in-go

Comment: Interesting how fast is string builder work relatively to other concatenations ways? Anyway bytes.Buffer and strings.Builder look preferred.

Comment: "cmd.Stdin = buf" is wrong, because of cannot use buf (type bytes.Buffer) as type io.Reader in assignment:
        bytes.Buffer does not implement io.Reader (Read method has pointer receiver)

Comment: everything ok with `cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(buf.String())` and strings.Builder

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with what you're doing now is that the concatenation operator `+` is an extremely inefficient way to combine a lot of strings into one bigger string.

How inefficient?  Well [here's a benchmark I did](https://johnrefior.com/gobits/read?post=10) testing three approaches:

```
BenchmarkMultiplyBasic                    300000              4240 ns/op
BenchmarkMultiplyJoinBasic                200000              9942 ns/op
BenchmarkMultiplyConcatenationsBasic       10000            170523 ns/op
```

The last one is the concatenate operator `+` and shows truly miserable performance compared to a couple alternatives.

Here's one approach that will be more efficient, in a simplified runnable example:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type result struct {
    s, r        string
    ss          int
}

func main() {
    a := []result{
        {"twas", "brillig", 1},
        {"and", "the", 2},
        {"slithy", "toves", 3},
    }
    outstrings := make([]string, 0)
    for _, part := range a {
        outstrings = append(outstrings, part.s, part.r, strconv.Itoa(part.ss))
    }
    out := strings.Join(outstrings, ` `)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", out)
}
```

prints

```
twas brillig 1 and the 2 slithy toves 3
```

How to most efficiently combine strings is a common question on StackOverflow and has been answered many times.  See this top-voted question/answer for Go: [How to efficiently concatenate strings in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760757/how-to-efficiently-concatenate-strings-in-go).

Comment: yes, that is why I wrote here... concatenation with "+" looks suspicious, and due to I'm newbie I simply don't know language details and thought Golang should have more beautiful ways to concatenate strings.