# Concatenate uuid in golang

Tags: go, uuid, string-concatenation

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760757/how-to-efficiently-concatenate-strings-in-go) how to convert string efficiently in GO using either `bytes.Buffer` or `strings.Builder`. So how do I achieve the same in uuid im using [satori/go.uuid](https://github.com/satori/go.uuid), since doing this

```
var buffer bytes.Buffer
var s string
for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
  s = buffer.WriteString(uuid.Must(uuid.NewV4()))
}
```

produce this error `Cannot use 'uuid.Must(uuid.NewV4())' as type string`.

My goal was so the 's' would be like this `15094a36-8827-453a-b27a-598421dbd73b-803bc133-dbc5-4629-9a2e-ef8ed3f1372e`

Comment: I'm using this https://github.com/satori/go.uuid, docs said uid is [16] byte type. how can I concatenate uuid then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `uuid.Must(uuid.NewV4())` is `uuid.UUID`, not `string`.  Call the `UUID.Sring()` method to get a `string`.  Call `buffer.String()` to get the `string` when done concatenating:

```
var buffer strings.Builder
for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    if i > 0 {
        buffer.WriteByte('-')
    }
    buffer.WriteString(uuid.Must(uuid.NewV4()).String())
}
s := buffer.String()
```

Another approach is to join the strings:

```
var uuids []string
for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    uuids = append(uuids, uuid.Must(uuid.NewV4()).String())
}
s := strings.Join(uuids, "-")
```

Comment: Add `buffer.WriteString("-")` to the concatenate, then remove the last char `"-"` from the concatenated string. Thanks Cerise!