# golang: specific question about string concatenation

Tags: string, go

OK we already have the answer that `StringBuilder` should be used to concatenate strings in `go`:

[How to efficiently concatenate strings in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760757/how-to-efficiently-concatenate-strings-in-go/47798475#47798475)

Now, I am reviewing a PR.
There is this code:

```
const CustomerID [32]byte

const paymentPrefix = "payment_done_"
￼const sentPrefix = "invoice_sent_"
￼const receivedPrefix = "invoice_received_"
￼
￼ 
func paymentKey(customer CustomerID) string {
￼   return paymentPrefix + customer.String()
}

// same for the other two Key
```

I am wondering if I should request to use `StringBuilder` here

```
func paymentKey(customer CustomerID) string {
  var str string.Builder
  str.WriteString(paymentPrefix)
  str.Write(customer)
  return str.String()
}
```

It is a 32 byte ID which first needs to be converted to `string` and then concatenated with `+`

These are only two strings but potentially called *a lot*, that is why I think it is justified to question concatenation.

Comment: Judging by the names you use here, I don't think it's justified to make it more complex than a simple `+`. Use `StringBuilder` if you have to add something to the string repeatedly. Don't over-optimize. Switch to `StringBuilder` if this proves to be a performance issue.

Comment: sounds reasonable @icza, thanks

Comment: customer.String() construction expect  that method String() would be implemented for type CustomerID. Can you be more precise. Also you use non UTF8 encoding in your snippet that is at least strange,

Comment: @faboolous:  "we already have the answer that StringBuilder should be used to concatenate strings in go". No we don't, it depends. The results are in for my first round of benchmarks: 61.4 ns/op for your Builder, 48.2 ns/op for your concatenation, 34.3 ns/op for my Builder, and 27.9 ns/op for my optimization.