# Performance comparison for concatenation of strings

Tags: performance, go, garbage-collection

I am trying to figure out the use of **strings.Join method** compared to **regular concatenation with +=**.

For this comparison, I am using both methods on os.Args as the list of strings to concatenate.

My code for the concatenating functions is:

```
func regular_concatenation() {
    var s, sep string
    for i := 1; i < len(os.Args); i++ {
        s += sep + os.Args[i]
        sep = " "
    }
    fmt.Println(s)
}

func join_concatenation() {
    fmt.Println(strings.Join(os.Args, " "))
}
```

And the main function for the performance check is:

```
func main() {
    var end_1, end_2 float64
    var start_1, start_2 time.Time

    start_1 = time.Now()
    for i:=0; i < 100; i++ {
        ex1_3_join_concatenation()
    }
    end_1 = time.Since(start_1).Seconds()

    start_2 = time.Now()
    for i:=0; i < 100; i++ {
        ex1_3_regular_concatenation()
    }
    end_2 = time.Since(start_2).Seconds()

    fmt.Println(end_1)
    fmt.Println(end_2)
}
```

Problem is - when I run the code, say with 20 arguments (os.Args), I get the result that the **strings.Join method is slower than the regular concatination**.

This is confusing for me, because the way I understood it - when using regular += method, it creates a new string reference each time (because strings are immutable in golang), therefore the garbage collector is supposed to run in order to collect the unused data and this wastes time.

So the question is - is strings.Join really a faster method? And if it is - what am I doing wrong in this example?

Comment: Start by creating a real, independent benchmarks; poor benchmarks give poor results. The join method will have fewer allocations, and will be faster provided there aren't other confounding variables. Your `join` function also handles one more argument than the other.

Comment: You have to google an info on how to benchmark go code, here's nothing to discuss, I think

Comment: well, I would suggest you ask the question about what's' wrong with this benchmark. Coz your simple question has a simple answer that `strings.Join` is faster than string concatenation.

Comment: One difference may be that you are adding os.Args[0] in the 2nd benchmark.

Comment: Try using an array of 1000 or so elements instead of os.Args and you will see that strings.Join is faster every time.

Answer (score 3):

Due to various compiler optimizations string concatenation *can* be quite efficient but in you case I found that `strings.Join` is faster (see benchmarks of your code below).

In general for building up a string it is recommended to use `strings.Builder`. See [How to efficiently concatenate strings in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760757/how-to-efficiently-concatenate-strings-in-go) .

BTW you should be using the brilliant benchmarking facility that comes with Go.  Just put these functions in a file ending with `_test.go` (eg string_test.go) and run `go test -bench=.`.

```
func BenchmarkConcat(b *testing.B) { // 132 ns/op
    ss := []string {"sadsadsa", "dsadsakdas;k", "8930984"}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        var s, sep string
        for j := 0; j < len(ss); j++ {
            s += sep + ss[j]
            sep = " "
        }
        _ = s
    }
}

func BenchmarkJoin(b *testing.B) {  // 56.7 ns/op
    ss := []string {"sadsadsa", "dsadsakdas;k", "8930984"}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        s := strings.Join(ss, " ")
        _ = s
    }
}

func BenchmarkBuilder(b *testing.B) { // 58.5
    ss := []string {"sadsadsa", "dsadsakdas;k", "8930984"}
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        var s strings.Builder
        // Grow builder to expected max length (maybe this
        // needs to be calculated dep. on your requirements)
        s.Grow(32)
        var sep string
        for j := 0; j < len(ss); j++ {
            s.WriteString(ss[j])
            s.WriteString(sep)
            sep = " "
        }
        _ = s.String()
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing to benchmark. Concatenation explicitly makes allocation per each meanwhile strings.Join is using a preallocated buffer. Ofc it might be faster in the case of 1-2 element concatenation because of less work.

Comment: There's no need to use a builder because it's what strings.Join do. In case of the known size, I'd use `make([]byte, size)` and `copy` if it requires to be fast

Comment: If there is nothing to benchmark it is weird that the code that i used with the "time" testing does not show the wanted results that you are speaking of (that strings.Join is faster either way), isn't it?

Comment: @Laevus Dexter sure creating your own buffer then using `copy` could perhaps be a little faster but you should provide the code so we can benchmark it. Personally I doubt it is much faster than `strings.Join` and it's always better to use a know good standard library function. BTW I don't understand what you mean by "there's nothing to benchmark" unless you mean that it's so obvious which is faster that there is no point.

Comment: I mean, heap allocations, in fact, is always slower than even long computations... So no need of benchmark for confirmation. Ye, I agree that if there std solution it's better to use that, but in "speed required" cases i'd make it maximally optimized. Btw, your testing code requires resetting timer before the loop

Comment: sure I upvoted this answer because it is really helpful information, but I can't why the answer to his true question - if join supposed to be faster, why in his case (without benchmark) it's not?