# Ho do various Go string concatenation approaches compare in terms of time and space complexity?

Tags: string, go, time-complexity, string-concatenation, space-complexity

1. `fmt.Sprintf("template with %s %s %s... placeholders", str1, str2 str3, ...)`
2. `fmt.Fprintf()` instead of `Sprintf()`
3. `str1 + str2 + str3 + ...`
4. using a `strings.Builder`'s `WriteString()` on the string pieces, and then return the result from the `String()` method

I am writing email service that generates SMTP messages which contains long chunks of Base64 encoded file contents, and involves lots of text concatenation to form headers. On high traffics, I try to avoid creating copies of Base64 file contents.

I wanna know if `strings.Builder` clearly wins over the other two approaches in terms of the efficiency of memory use and time taken.

Comment: Have you tried Google? I remember seeing more than one article specifically on this topic some time ago.

Comment: Most likely you should be taking advantage of the writer interface and continuously writing your string pieces to the connection.  There's no sense in building up a big string in memory when you can just stream the pieces one by one to the end destination.  See https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#Client.Data

Comment: If you're interested there is also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760757/how-to-efficiently-concatenate-strings-in-go/1766304