# How to retrieve the first “complete” character of a []rune?

Tags: unicode, go, rune

I am trying to write a function

```
func Anonymize(name string) string
```

that anonymizes names. Here are some examples of pairs of input and output so you get an idea of what it is supposed to do:

```
Müller → M.
von der Linden → v. d. L.
Meyer-Schulze → M.-S.
```

This function is supposed to work with names composed out of arbitrary characters. While implementing this function, I had the following question:

Given a `[]rune` or `string`, how do I figure out how many runes I have to take to get a complete character, complete in the sense that all modifiers and combining accents corresponding to the character are taken, too. For instance, if the input is `[]rune{0x0041, 0x0308, 0x0066, 0x0067}` (corresponding to the string ÄBC where Ä is represented as the combination of an A and a combining diaresis), the function should return 2 because the first two runes yield the first character, Ä. If I just took the first rune, I would get A which is incorrect.

I need an answer to this question because the name I want to anonymize might begin with an accented character and I don't want to remove the accent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following function (inspired by "[Go language string length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12668681/6309)"):

```
func FirstGraphemeLen(str string) int {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("\\PM\\pM*|.")
    return len([]rune(re.FindAllString(str, -1)[0]))
}
```

See [this example](http://play.golang.org/p/-6btvtix4U):

```
r := []rune{0x0041, 0x0308, 0x0066, 0x0041, 0x0308, 0x0067}
s := string(r)
fmt.Println(s, len(r), FirstGraphemeLen(s))
```

Output:

```
ÄfÄg 6 2
```

That string might use 6 runes, but its first grapheme uses 2.

---

The [OP FUZxxl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417501/fuzxxl) used another approach, using [`unicode.IsMark(r)`](http://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsMark)

> `IsMark` reports whether the rune is a **mark character** (category M).

The source (from FUZxxl's [play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/yjzmGsqltG)) includes:

```
// take one character including all modifiers from the last name
r, _, err := ln.ReadRune()
if err != nil {
    /* ... */
}

aln = append(aln, r)

for {
    r, _, err = ln.ReadRune()
    if err != nil {
        goto done
    }

    if !unicode.IsMark(r) {
        break
    }

    aln = append(aln, r)
}

aln = append(aln, '.')
/* ... */
```

Comment: This helped, although I didn't use a regex in the actual code. Here is [how I've done it](http://play.golang.org/p/yjzmGsqltG).

Comment: @FUZxxl IsMark works too, indeed. I have included your solution in the answer for more visibility.