# replace strings n times, starting from the end

Tags: string, go

It is my second day with golang, I'll probably ask a very basic question:

I want to replace parts of a string, that is what [strings.Replace](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace) is good for:

```
func Replace(s, old, new string, n int) string
```

The last parameter is the number of times `old` gets replaced by `new` - starting from the beginning of the string.

Is there a similar standard function that starts from the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such standard function you seek for.

### Alternative #1: with Reverse

Using a string-reverse function (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752414/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-go)):

```
func Rev(s string) string {
    runes := []rune(s)
    for i, j := 0, len(runes)-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        runes[i], runes[j] = runes[j], runes[i]
    }
    return string(runes)
}
```

Your solution is:

```
Rev(strings.Replace(Rev(s), Rev(old), Rev(new), n))
```

### Alternative #2: do-it-yourself

You can simply use a `for` and [`strings.LastIndex()`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#LastIndex) to find replacable substrings and replace them.